# Choose slices from numpy array B if cond else from A

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays like this:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([100, 100, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 3, 5], dtype=int)
A = np.reshape(A, (2,2,3))
B = np.array([3, 6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 100, 3, 2, 100, 100, 5])
B = np.reshape(B, (2,2,3))

print(repr(A))
# array([[[100, 100,   3],
#         [  0,   0,   0]],

#        [[  0,   0,   0],
#         [100,   3,   5]]])

print(repr(B))
# array([[[  3,   6,   2],
#         [  6,   3,   2]],

#        [[100,   3,   2],
#         [100, 100,   5]]])
```

What I'd like to do is to select 2x3 slices from `B` where at least one value is > 10. Where this condition is not met, I want the corresponding slice from `A`, like this:

```
# desired result 
out = np.array([100, 100, 3, 0, 0, 0, 100, 3, 2, 100, 100, 5])
out = np.reshape(out, (2,2,3))

print(repr(out))
# array([[[100, 100,   3],
#         [  0,   0,   0]],

#        [[100,   3,   2],
#         [100, 100,   5]]])
```

I can find the indices I want:

```
filt = ~np.all(B < 10, axis=2)
```

But I'm not sure how to extract them. I've come up with this horrible hack:

```
A2 = np.reshape(A, (4,3))
B2 = np.reshape(B, (4,3))
filt2 = np.reshape(filt, 4)

res2 = np.array([[B2[i] if filt2[i] else A2[i] for i in range(0,4)]])
res = np.reshape(res2, (2,2,3))
np.all(res == out)
Out[88]: True
```

There's probably a more direct way, and I suspect it's NumPy select, but I haven't figured out how to make the dimensions fit. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this:

```
print(np.where(np.any(B > 10, axis=2)[..., None], B,  A))

# [[[100 100   3]
#   [  0   0   0]]

#  [[100   3   2]
#   [100 100   5]]]
```

`np.any(B > 10, axis=2)` is equivalent to your `filt` index. Since you are reducing over the last axis, it will yield a `(2,  2)` array, whereas `A` and `B` are both `(2,  2,  3)`, so `np.where(np.any(B > 10, axis=2), B, A)` would raise an indexing error.

Fortunately, `np.where` supports [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), so you can simply insert a new final axis of size 1 by indexing with `None`, and `np.where` will effectively treat it as a `(2, 2, 3)` array consisting of your `filt` index repeated 3 times. You could achieve the same effect by passing `keepdims=True` to `np.any` to retain the singleton final dimension:

```
np.where(np.any(B > 10, axis=2,  keepdims=1), B,  A)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([100, 100, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 3, 5], dtype=int)
A = np.reshape(A, (2,2,3))
B = np.array([3, 6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 100, 3, 2, 100, 100, 5])
B = np.reshape(B, (2,2,3))

B[B<10] = A[B<10]
# out = B
```

Using numpy slicing, you can compare and replace values between size matched arrays easily. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Almost, but not quite

    B   # your result 
    Out[13]:
    array([[[100, 100,   3],
            [  0,   0,   0]],

           [[100,   0,   0],
            [100, 100,   5]]])

    out  # desired result 
    Out[15]:
    array([[[100, 100,   3],
            [  0,   0,   0]],

          [[100,   3,   2],
           [100, 100,   5]]])

Your solution loses the values in the third row.

Comment: Yes that's what I get for B after B[B<10] = A[B<10].

Comment: In my hackish solution, the result is filtering on the innermost level of the ndarray. Imagine that it's an 2d array of cells (rather than a 3d array of ints), and we're operating on the cells (not on the ints). Does that help?